# Why is the "wrong" interpretation of confidence intervals still seemingly correct?

Tags: statistics

According to online sources, if you are operating at 95% confidence, it means if you repeated a sampling process many times and then looked at the 95% confidence intervals over all the results, 95% of the time the brackets would contain the true population mean.

But then they say that it is NOT the same as saying "you can be 95% confident that the intervals you computed contain the population mean."

Isn't it, though? For instance I do my first experiment and get a 95% confidence interval. Then a second. Third, fourth, ..., 100th. 95 of those intervals should contain the population mean. Is this correct so far?

If so, then why isn't it the same as me saying, from the moment I did the very first test, "this particular interval has a 95% chance at being one of the intervals that contain the true population mean"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly the probability that the interval you will get contains the population mean is $0.95$, but the *conditional* probability given the numbers that you got can be different.  Here are four examples, one of which (the second) is realistic.

- One instance where that would obviously happen is when you *know* the population mean, so that the conditional probability given what you know about both the population and the sample would be either $0$ or $1$.
- A less extreme example is when you have a prior probability distribution for the population mean and your confidence interval falls within some region where the mean is unlikely to be.  This can happen in some practical situations.
- A more disturbing case goes like this: Suppose you have a sample of size $3$ from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,A]$ and your confidence interval for the population mean $A/2$ is $[B\bar X,C\bar X]$ where $\bar X$ is the sample mean.  I leave it as an exercise to find the correct values of $B$ and $C$ to make this a $95\%$ confidence interval.  Now suppose the sample you get is $1,2,99$, so that $\bar X=34$ and the confidence interval is $[34B,34C]$.  If I'm not mistaken, the confidence interval excludes $99/2 = 49.5$, but in fact you *know* that the mean is at least $99/2$ in this case!  The data alone tell you that this is one of the other $5\%$.  (This one is of course easily remedied by observing that the minimal sufficient statistic is the maximum observed value, and then using a confidence interval of the form $[B'\max,C'\max]$, where $B'$ and $C'$ would both be less than $1$.)
- A case that is perhaps even more disturbing is this.  Two independent observations are uniformly distributed between $A-1/2$ and $A+1/2$.  Call the larger of these $\max$ and the smaller $\min$.  Clearly $[\min,\max]$ is a $50\%$ confidence interval for $A$.  But if $\max-\min=0.0001$ then you would be a fool if you did not find it highly improbable that $A$ is between them, and if $\max-\min=0.9999$ you would be a fool if you were not nearly $100\%$ sure that $A$ is between them.  This technique gives you a $50\%$ coverage rate, but the data tell you whether the instance you've got is likely to be among that $50\%$ or not.  (This one also has a standard remedy: Ronald Fisher's technique of conditioning on an ancillary statistic, which in this case is $\max-\min$.  You get a more reasonable $50\%$ confidence interval.  I don't remember the details, but it is the same as the posterior distribution when you use an improper uniform prior on the real line.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  Bullet point 2 coupled with example 2 here (http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/06/12/frequentism-and-bayesianism-3-confidence-credibility/) suddenly let me to a breakthrough in my visceral understanding of mis-interpretations of confidence intervals as probabilities.

Comment: @joshphysics : Thank you.

Comment: Great answer! I posted a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605530/correct-interpretation-of-probabilities-vs-confidence